# Problem with PyWeka3 attribute_names() and subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, subset, weka

I have this code of PyWeka3:

```
from weka.core.converters import load_any_file

data = load_any_file("/home/pablo/Escritorio/weka-3-9-5/data/iris.arff")

print(data.attribute_names(), data.num_instances)

# select columns by name
subset = data.subset(col_names=['sepallength', 'sepalwidth', 'petallength', 'petalwidth'])
print(subset.attribute_names(), subset.num_instances)

# select columns by range (1-based indices)
subset = data.subset(col_range='1-3,5')
print(subset.attribute_names(), subset.num_instances)

# select rows by range (1-based indices)
subset = data.subset(row_range='51-150')
print(subset.attribute_names(), subset.num_instances)

# invert selection of cols/rows and keep original relation name
subset = data.subset(col_range='5', invert_cols=True, row_range='51-150', invert_rows=True, keep_relationame=True)
print(subset.attribute_names(), subset.num_instances)
```

And i'm haveing problems with this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2852/126033928.py in <module>
      3 data = load_any_file("/home/pablo/Escritorio/weka-3-9-5/data/iris.arff")
      4 
----> 5 print(data.attribute_names(), data.num_instances)
      6 
      7 # select columns by name

AttributeError: 'Instances' object has no attribute 'attribute_names'
```

Don't know how to solve it, i tried to add the attribute called 'attributed_names' and the error disappear but don't show nothing.

Also if i comment this line i get the next subset error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2852/1663248871.py in <module>
      6 
      7 # select columns by name
----> 8 subset = data.subset(col_names=['sepallength', 'sepalwidth', 'petallength', 'petalwidth'])
      9 print(subset.attribute_names(), subset.num_instances)
     10 

AttributeError: 'Instances' object has no attribute 'subset'
```

All this code is obteined from https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html#dataset-subsets

Comment: Are you sure you installed `python-weka-wrapper3` (for Python 3) and not `python-weka-wrapper` (for Python 2.7, which is no longer maintained)? Try a `pip freeze` in your environment. I successfully ran that piece of example code in a freshly installed virtual environment using `virtualenv` (using Python 3.8.10). `pip freeze`: Cython==0.29.24, numpy==1.21.2, javabridge==1.0.19, python-weka-wrapper3==0.2.3.

Comment: I have numpy == 1.20.3, Cython==0.29.24, javabridge==1.0.19 and i have installed both, python-weka-wrapper 0.3.18 and python-weka-wrapper3 0.2.3. @fracpete

Comment: ok thanks i solve it thanks you so much

Comment: Installing the Python 2.7 version as well will cause problems, of course.